# XSLT Count total number of rows in a Table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I'm working with XML that contains HTML Table with rowspan. I need to get the total amount of cols and rows of this table, I need to work this with xslt to do a transformation. 
I'm trying to do something like this :

```
<xsl:value of select="count(./tr) - count(./tr/td/@rowspan > 1 and ./tr/td =1)"</xsl:value-of>
```

Of course, this doesn't work because I have some `<tr>` with more than one `<td>` . I need to count only when this two conditions are checked. I assume xslt looks ALL the `<tr>` and doesn't check in the same  where the first condition is true.

Any help/suggestion?

In this Example, we have 5  , but the "real" count of  should be 4. (The HTML output has 4 rows).

```
 <table border="2">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="3" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" rowspan="3" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" rowspan="2" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    text
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see only 2 rows that have more than one `td` element. You can count them using this expression: `<xsl:value-of select="count(table/tr[count(td) > 1] )"/>`. If that's not what you mean, then please explain in simple words what the conditions are.

Comment: I need to count all the rows with rowspan > 1, that have more than one td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to count all the rows with rowspan > 1, that have more than one
>   td.

There is only one like that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(table/tr[td/@rowspan > 1 and count(td) > 1] )"/>
```